# minus two tables with primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

I have sql database with tables:

> sc: s_id, m_id
>
> s: id, name
>
> m: id, name
>
> sc_standart: s_id, m_id
>
> s_standart: id, name
>
> m_standart: id, name

sc.s_id is from s.id, sc.m_id is from m.id, sc_standart.s_id is from s_standart.id, sc_standart.m_id is from m_standart.id.

I should set m_id=null for all lines from sc which are not exist in sc_standart.

I had already written:

```
SELECT s.name, m.name 
FROM s
JOIN sc
   ON s.id=sc.s_id
JOIN m
   ON m.id=sc.m_id
MINUS
SELECT s_standart.name, m_standart.name 
FROM s_standart
JOIN sc_standart
   ON s_standart.id=sc_standart.s_id
JOIN m_standart
   ON m_standart.id=sc_standart.m_id
```

So I should update (s_id, m_id) lines relevant to (s.name, m.name) from the select above.

Comment: If the rule is *set m_id=null for all lines from sc which do not exist in sc_standart*, then what do the other tables  have to do with it? Only `sc` and `sc_standart` have an `m_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could just do it as:

```
update sc
set    m_id = null
where  not exists
       ( select 1 from sc_standart s
         where  s.m_id = sc.m_id )
```

Or using `minus`:

```
update sc
set    m_id = null
where  m_id in
       ( select m_id from sc
         minus
         select m_id from sc_standart )
```

However, I might be missing something as I couldn't see how the other four tables were related to your question.